# Express session not persisting between api calls from react front end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, express-session

Before asking this, I did have a look at other similar questions, but none of them have been of help as of yet.

I have a react front-end using axios to make api calls to a node backend using express and express session. Once I enter login info on my front end, I send it to my backend where I set a session and return a response to the front end that I set in the localStorage to use for client side validation.

When I try to access a protected api endpoint - from the front end - after logging in, the session does not have any of the information I set in it and thus, gives me an error. However, if I try to login and access the protected endpoint from postman, it works perfectly fine.

Here is my express-session config:

```
router.use(session({
 secret: 'notGoingToWork',
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: true
}))
```

Here is the api call (after logging in) I am making through axios:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/users/personNotes/${JSON.parse(userData).email}`)
    .then(response => console.log(response);
```

I do not know what the issue is and would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `withCredentials`

```
axios(`http://localhost:5000/users/personNotes/${JSON.parse(userData).email}`, {
  method: "get",
  withCredentials: true
})
```

or

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Comment: I tried it, I still get the same 404 not found error on the front end and I cant find any of the data I set in the session object on the backend.

Comment: @ParthPatel You never mentioned `404 Not found` error in the initial question. Please add more code regarding the routes part on the server.

Comment: I've tested the backend with postman and it works perfectly. The only reason i get back a 404 not found is because I send a 404 response from my backend if the session does not exist.

Comment: am I supposed to use `withCredentials: true` everywhere? Should I use it in the axios post while I login as well?

Comment: You can change the `axios.defaults.withCredentials` as I mention in the answer, then you dont have to do it in each request. So it worked?

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Along with that you need to add this also in case using node+express   app.use(cors({
  origin:['http://localhost:3000'],
  methods:['GET','POST'],
  credentials: true // enable set cookie
}));

Answer (score 1):

You can use **axios** try `withCredentials` to `true`.

For **fetch** with `credentials` to `include` will also work.

```
fetch(URL, 
 {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  headers: new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To use fetch with

```
credentials: 'include'
```

I also had to add the following in Express App.js.

To note, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' cannot set to '*' with credentials. It must use a specific domain name.

```
res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        'http://localhost:3000'
    );
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```